# Serving pdf files by link, downloaded as pdf.html

Tags: python, django

Crated function to allow users download pdf files by link. Works fine, the only problem that what user save is .html. So all files are file.pdf.html.

```
def download(request,ticket_id):
    ticket_path = str(Ticket.objects.get(id=ticket_id).upload)
    with open('files/media/' + ticket_path, 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read())
        response['content_type'] = 'application/pdf'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="file.pdf"'
        return response
```

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move `content_type` into `HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')`, it's an [attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#attributes) of HttpResponse